# What is the proper way to declare global variables

Tags: javascript, global, hoisting

I know about hoisting.

But I wonder what the recommended solution is for a global array, for instance, that functions as a lookup table. An array that you would declare constant and make global in most languages.

Like:

```
 var lookup = ["010101010", "0100101010", "01010101010", "etc"];

 function foo() {    
     // lookup is undefined
 }
```

I could pass it in, I guess. Or make it part of window.document. Or some trick with 'this' that I don't fully understand. What's the best way to do this?

**Edit**: Right, after reading the comments, I now realize, the problem I was experiencing wasn't caused by hoisting. There was some other problem in my code. It works now. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: The best way is to avoid global variables altogether.

Comment: `lookup` is not undefined in that function so long as you define `lookup` before you call `foo()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure that you declare `lookup` before the function `foo` is called. See the following snippet. If you declare it after `foo` is called, you will get the error `undefined`.

```js
var lookup = ["010101010", "0100101010", "01010101010", "etc"];
foo();
 function foo() {    
     console.log(lookup);
 }
```

Comment: You won't get "undefined error" you'll get the value as `undefined`.

Comment: @teemu, Pardon my incorrect verbiage. I have tweaked it.

Comment: I mean that there won't be any errors triggered, you just get `undefined` as a value of `lookup` if it's declared using `var` after the function call (because of hoisting). A value is not an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store some static data, use of static methods :

```
class CONSTANT {

  /**
   * Public method that will return a new array you can manipulate
   *
   * It's different of this.MY_CONSTANT = [X, Y, Z];
   *
   * Because accessing this.MY_CONSTANT will gives you an access to
   * the same element (if you modify it, it will get
   * modified for the next use of it)
   */
  static get MY_CONSTANT() {
    return [ 
        '010101010', 
        '0100101010',
        '01010101010',
    ];
  }

}
```

---

To access :

```
CONSTANT.MY_CONSTANT
```

---

**Ps**: It requires **ES6**

Comment: I think you want `class CONSTANT {}` not  `class CONSTANT() {}`

Comment: Class declarations aren't hoisted, which means you need to make this declaration before you can use it. Why would you do this instead of simply declaring a `const` at the top of the file.

Comment: Because I think it's better to centralize constant values in your code, in order to make it simplier to read. You can also use a const at the top of the file ofc. It depends the constant you are making and if you would require it elsewhere in your code.